# Cannot pass form data to SQLite using getElementById

Tags: javascript, sqlite

I cannot pass data from HTML Form to SQLite using `getElementById`.

This is a very simple code for learning about how use SQLite for permanent storage.

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
var db = openDatabase('sightings', '1.0', 'Test DB', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
var msg;


function InsertValues() {
var mydata = document.getElementById("CommonName").value;
db.transaction(function (tx) {      
  tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Sights (CommonName CHAR(17), location CHAR(32), datte CHAR(10), Observations CHAR(90))');
  tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO Sights (CommonName,location,datte,Observations) VALUES (mydata,"loobo","loobo","loobo")');
  msg = '<p>Log message created and row inserted.</p>';
  document.querySelector('#status').innerHTML =  msg;
});
}


function myfunction2() {
db.transaction(function (tx) {
  tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM Sights', [], function (tx, results) {
   var len = results.rows.length, i;
   msg = "<p>Found rows: " + len + "</p>";
   document.querySelector('#status').innerHTML +=  msg;
   for (i = 0; i < len; i++){
     msg = "<p><b>" + results.rows.item(i).CommonName + "</b></p>";
     document.querySelector('#status').innerHTML +=  msg;
   }
 }, null);
});
}
</script>

</head>


<body>
<div class="observation">
  <h1></h1>
  <form action="#" method="post">
    <fieldset>
      <label for="name" >Common Name:</label>
      <input type="text" id="CommonName" placeholder=" Bird common Name" />
      <label for="name" >Location:</label>
      <input type="text" id="location" placeholder=" Where you see it" />
      <label for="email">Date</label>
      <input type="date" id="date" placeholder="mm/dd/yyy" /> 
      <label for="message">Observations:</label>
      <textarea id=" Observations" placeholder="What you see"></textarea>    
    <input type="submit" value="Register" onclick="InsertValues();">        
    </fieldset>
  </form>

</div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
            myfunction2();
 </script>
<div id="status" name="status">Status Message</div>

</body>
</html>
```

What issue is preventing the data flow from the HTML Form to SQLite?

Comment: [MDN docs for SQlite storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Storage) "available to trusted callers, meaning extensions and Firefox components only".  The API is "subject to change at any time" and is tagged "fixit" and "needs technical review".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get string values from your code into an SQL statement, use parameters:

```
tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO Sights (CommonName,location,datte,Observations) '+
              'VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)',
              [mydata, 'loobo', 'loobo', 'loobo']);
```